# How to make successful connection to GOAT endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to access a hidden API for goat.com https://www.goat.com/web-api/v1/product_variants/buy_bar_data?productTemplateId=884794&countryCode=US using python requests.
I'm using ID 884794 as an example. When I go to make a get request I keep getting 403'd no matter what I try. I've tried different user agents and proxies and none work. Im pretty sure its something to do with the csrf token but I'm unsure how to obtain it and use it in my code below.

```
import requests
import json

#make a request to the given url
url = 'https://www.goat.com/web-api/v1/product_variants/buy_bar_data?productTemplateId=884794&countryCode=US'
headers = { "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"101\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"101\"",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
        "sec-fetch-site": "none",
        "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(f'html response: {response}')
```

Comment: Great question, I tried and it works everywhere except in requests. httpie works